# Is it possible to use power apps to create a login page using office365 email and password for credential submission

Tags: user-interface, sharepoint, passwords, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm creating a powerapp interface for a small corporation that using office365/sharepoint to log in to their network. Is it possible to use both the username or email and password to login and pass on to the next screen? so far this is what I’m working with "-----" don't know what to use.

```
If (User().Email = Txt_Inpt_Us, User().
```

and

```
If(User().Email exactin Txt_Inpt_Us.Text).------ = Txt_Inpt_Pas.Text, false, true)
```

I've tried various combinations and combing through powerapps help but am growing tired and wanted to get y'alls take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerApps will be used by internal employees in a corporate using Azure AD user account, which is used for Single signon across Sharepoint, O365, etc. In some cases external guests can be shared with this PowerApp but still they have to be in some AAD and invited through your company AAD as guests.

That being said, Authentication for PowerApp is already taken care by Azure AD challenge. Not sure why you want to have a separate login screen to mimic the behavior.

In case you want some registration process to use and authorization on multiple role/persona, then you should maintain a separate database to handle the entitlements and authorization.

Don’t forget, this is going to be extra step for users, to get authenticated in addition to AAD always.

Comment: Ah thanks didnt think about that part. Yes we were wanting specific roles, such as leadershiproles havingnthe ability to email a pdf if the document or create a new file for the month, print current, etc.

Comment: @RobisDoyal it’s a common scenario, so build a separate app for each persona.. so you can avoid headaches :) if this answer helped you, upvote/accept it to help others to find it useful.

Comment: I've posted another power app question you might be able to help me with if your willing.